# Android service not running firebase

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Hello i have a problem my service not running i dont no why :/

I code a code, to find out if the service is running it is not running

service for firebase

my manifest :
i paste in pastebin because error lenght
 pastebin.com/FkAxZZM4

```
 @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
   storeToken(refreshedToken);
}
```

this not working

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            sendPushNotification(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from where u r firing the notification

Comment: what i dont understand

Comment: are you triggering the notifiactions from console